# Convert updated_at date format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

I have a variable `response` which return the below value

```
[
 {"id"=>"1", "updated_at"=>Fri, 18 Nov 2016 20:27:03 UTC +00:00},
 {"id"=>"2", "updated_at"=>Fri, 18 Nov 2016 14:54:51 UTC +00:00}
]
```

I want to modified the `updated_at` date format

My desired Format is:

```
[
 {"id"=>"1", "updated_at"=>"2016-11-18T20:27:03Z"}, 
 {"id"=>"2", "updated_at"=>"2016-11-18T14:54:51Z"}
]
```

Comment: are you trying tot render the date in a view, or in a json?

Comment: @MZaragoza json

Comment: @MZaragoza json. I am testing from rails console.`response.updated_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")` I got error 
`NoMethodError: undefined method 'updated_at' for #<Array:0x00000004752c00`

Comment: did you set the response to be something like `response = User.last` ?

Comment: I used `as_json`. It worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the format that you are looking for is `response.updated_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")`

Create a method in your model that you can use to format the date, I called it **formatted_updated_at**

```
def formatted_updated_at
  updated_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
end
```

and

`response.to_json(methods: [:formatted_updated_at])`

or

`format.json { render json: response.to_json(include: :formatted_updated_at) }`

I hope that this helps

:)

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked `response.as_json(methods: [:formatted_updated_at])`